# warning: Duplicated ref when git push

Tags: git, warnings

when push master branch to remote target:tmp

```
git push tmp master
```

i get this message

```
warning: Duplicated ref: refs/heads/master
```

push can still success.

but what is this message mean?
how can i find more detail log info about this?

this is my .git/config

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = false
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  symlinks = false
  ignorecase = true
  hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = git@github.com:testuser/myproject.git
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "tmp"]
  url = git@192.168.1.44:testuser/myproject.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/tmp/*
```

and my git version is `1.7.11.msysgit.1`

---

`show-ref` and `ls-remote` info

```
$ git show-ref
1696d17186db41cc70876f76f943e18ea4708ad3 refs/heads/master
3c51688bf27e712001db1b6e9f316748634643c4 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
3c51688bf27e712001db1b6e9f316748634643c4 refs/remotes/origin/master
1696d17186db41cc70876f76f943e18ea4708ad3 refs/remotes/tmp/master

$ git ls-remote tmp
warning: Duplicated ref: refs/heads/master
1696d17186db41cc70876f76f943e18ea4708ad3        HEAD
1696d17186db41cc70876f76f943e18ea4708ad3        refs/heads/master

$ git ls-remote origin
3c51688bf27e712001db1b6e9f316748634643c4        HEAD
3c51688bf27e712001db1b6e9f316748634643c4        refs/heads/master
```

output of `git show-ref` on tmp

```
$ git show-ref
warning: Duplicated ref: refs/heads/master
1696d17186db41cc70876f76f943e18ea4708ad3 refs/heads/master
```

content of `packed-refs` on tmp

```
# pack-refs with: peeled 
3c51688bf27e712001db1b6e9f316748634643c4 refs/heads/master
3c51688bf27e712001db1b6e9f316748634643c4 refs/heads/master
```

output of `find .` in bare repo `myproject.git`. the objects folder has too many subfolers, so i don't paste them.

```
$ find .
.
./branches
./packed-refs
./objects
./HEAD
./info
./info/exclude
./config
./description
./refs
./refs/tags
./refs/heads
./refs/heads/master
./hooks
./hooks/commit-msg.sample
./hooks/update.sample
./hooks/pre-commit.sample
./hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
./hooks/post-update.sample
./hooks/pre-rebase.sample
./hooks/post-receive
./hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
./hooks/update
./hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, it means that you somehow ended creating another ref that has the name master, but doesn't live in the normal location.  The few times I've seen this it's because I was messing with a plumbing command and didn't provide the full path to the ref (`refs/heads/master`) when the command expected one.  First, let's get your local repository up-to-date with the remote with:

```
git fetch --all
```

Check your local repository first with:

```
git show-ref | grep -i master
```

The `-i` is in there because you're on Windows, and case sensitivity can be an issue.  I suspect you might see something like `refs/master` in the list.  The idea is that there's a name that could be resolved two ways. `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/remotes/tmp/master` are okay since they're namespaced properly.

If that doesn't turn up anything, check the remote:

```
git ls-remote url://to/remote/repo.git | grep master
```

I suspect the issue is in your local repository.  For the local repository, you can remove the ref via `update-ref`:

```
git update-ref -m 'remove duplicate ref' -d <duplicate ref>
```

Where `<duplicate ref>` is the extra one you found from the `show-ref` command.  **Branches are stored under `refs/heads`.  Be careful not to delete `refs/heads/master`.**

If it's on the remote, you should be able to remove the duplicate via:

```
git push origin :<duplicate ref>
```

Where `<duplicate ref>` is the extra one found by the `ls-remote` command above.  **Again, be careful here.  Do not use `master` or `refs/heads/master`.**

If possible, update your question with the output of `git show-ref` and the `git ls-remote`.  Also, I can walk you through it in the comments to help make sure you don't lose any data.

**Now that we see packed-refs is the culprit**

So the problem is that `packed-refs` has more than one line referring to master.  I'm not entirely sure how that come to be, but I suspect there was a version of git that allowed it to slide through.  A `git gc` will caused `packed-refs` to be re-written, so I'd just do that on your `tmp` remote.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I add some detail info, it seems that tmp had a duplicate ref. Should i just remove that ref?

Comment: Do you have direct access to tmp?  I don't think we can fix this via a remote operation.  If you have direct access, let's do a few things.  First, go to that repo and run `git show-ref`.  I imagine it's going to show us the same things as `git ls-remote`, but let's see.  Secondly, run 'find .' with in the bare repository (myproject.git).  Finally, cat the output of packed-refs and update your answer with those outputs.

Comment: FYI, given the output of `ls-remote`, we're probably going to delete `refs/heads/master` (either via `git push` or `git update-ref`--the latter will require access to the server) on tmp and then have you re-push to master from your working tree.  But I'd like to make sure that nothing else is wrong first.  BTW, what version of git is installed on the tmp remote?

Comment: I updated the info, and the outputs of `ls-remote` and `ls-remote origin` were the same.

Comment: the git version of tmp was `1.7.9.5`, and local version was `git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1`. many thanks.

Comment: It looks like a `git gc` on the tmp repo will do the trick.  `git gc` will repack the objects and the packed refs, which will cause the file to be rewritten without the duplicate line.